# JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, runtime-error, undefined

My project is in MVC 4. My scripts are in _Layout.cshtml when reload the page the following error: JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

_Layout.cshtml:

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="~/Images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") 
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js"> </script>
 </head>
```

My Partial View:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

       $('#lnkOrganizar').click(function () {
       if (($('.frozenTopC').css('display') != 'none') &&      ($('.frozenTopConteudo').css('display') != 'none')) {
           $('.frozenTopC').css('display', 'none');
           $('.frozenTopConteudo').css('display', 'none');
        }
        else {
         $('.frozenTopC').css('display', 'table-cell');
         $('.frozenTopConteudo').css('display', 'table-cell')
        }
     });

  </script>
```

Comment: Please check if your jQuery is loading properly. Otherwise there is no other reason for this error.

Comment: Are you sure that jQuery has been included?  E.g. if you view the source of the final output, does it successfully resolve the link to jQuery?

Comment: Does the rendered code has a working link to the jQuery library?

Comment: be sure to wrap your script in `$(window).load(function(){});` to be sure your script run when the page is ready, and not before the jquery is loaded and make sure, jquery loaded before `jtip`

Comment: Open the dev tools in your browser. Look at the HTML code: Is the jQuery lib in your page? Is the URL correct? Is there a 404 error for it? (or any other error?)

Comment: @ Spudley I opened the browser and appears and the following scripts: <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"> </ script> <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"> </ script> <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"> </ script> <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"> </ script> <roteiro src = "/ Scripts / jquery.validate.js"> </ script> <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"> </ script> <tipo de script = "text / javascript" src = " / Scripts/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js "> </ script>

Comment: @IliyaReyzis To use `$(window).load(function(){});` _jQuery_ needs to be already available at the time this is called. So `[...] and not before the jquery is loaded [...]` is wrong. If the script is executed before _jQuery_ is available (loaded and executed) you get the `'$' is undefined` error.

Comment: @t.niese yes, and thats why I added `[...]make sure, jquery loaded before jtip[...]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jquery isn't present.

Look at this line:  `<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js"> </script>`

Check that you have that `Scripts/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js` on the server

It is also NOT usual to refer to your home directory there - where you have the "`~`".  If your script is in a `Scripts` directory then you just use `Scripts/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js` because with a web server, everything is within it's root (top level) directory.

Also is this file the main jquery library?  It's not clear to me whether this is just your script code and if so you'll need to include the main js library with something like:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

btw, aim to use lowercase for directory names - `scripts` not `Scripts` as it will make your life easier in the long run.  I would also recommend `script` not `scripts` as many directories have multiple files (their purpose after all) so most folks use singular directory.  This is closer to a preference though than the `~` issue.

Also, while debugging and playing around, remember that you can actually have the script in the same file, within `<script>` tags, not in a separate file.  Not recommended long-term as a good practice but useful for seeing where the issue is.